# Powershell working with SQL Server datasets

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, dataset

I was trying to filter the dataset that i got from SQL server database. Here is the scenario...

I'm getting servername,dbname columns from one of the database servers and returning the result set as `return ,$dataSet.Tables[0]`. I'm getting the results correctly in a table format.

But now i got all the server names to a variable from this dataset as below,

```powershell
$servers=$dataSet_1.servername | select  -unique
```

Now, i'm trying to loop through each server and get the database list associated to each server as follows, but looks like this is not a right approach as it is getting me all the severs and their database names is every iteration

```powershell
foreach($server IN $servers)
{
     write-host $server
     $dataSet_1 | Where-Object {$dataSet_1.servername -eq $server} | select $_.dbname
}
```

Could someone help me the right approach are a way to do this.

Sample output: (Basically it should iterate each server and display its databasename)

ServerA

dbname

database1
database2
database3
....

ServerB

dbname

database1
database8
database10
....

ServerC
...

Thanks,

Comment: Please include sample data for input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: here is the output should look like,

ServerA

dbname
------
database1
database2
database3


ServerB

dbname
------
database1
database5
database10

ServerC

....

Comment: Please don't add data as comment. It is hard to read. Edit your question and add *all* the asked data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$dataSet_1 | where {$_.servername -eq $server} " is still returning the System.Data.DataTable type.

Does this return the desired output?

```
$dataSet_1 | where {$_.servername -eq $server}  | %{$_.dbname}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```powershell
$servers=$dataSet_1.servername | Select-Object -Unique
$filteredSet = $dataSet_1 | Where-Object { $servers -contains $_.servername }

$filteredSet
```

Comment: when executing your code i got following exception.
`Select-Object : Property "servername" cannot be found.
At line:54 char:38
+     $servers=$dataSet_1.servername | Select-Object -Unique -ExpandProperty serve ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (SERVER-A:PSObject) [Select-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpandPropertyNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand`

Comment: but the following code collects all servers from the dataset
`$servers=$dataSet_1.servername | select  -unique `

From here how to recurse the servernames to get associated dbnames for each server in $servers.

Comment: I edited the code; does it work now? Please note it's difficult to tell what your `$dataSet_1` object contains, so I'm going by context clues.

Comment: I didn't get any exceptions now...but the code returns nothing.

My dataset got two properties servername & dbname. I would like to recurse each server and collect database names associated to each server. something like ..

`
foreach($server IN $servers)
{
    
$dataSet_1 | Where-Object { $_.servername -eq $server} | Select dbname
    
}`

Comment: I have edited again. `$filteredSet` now contains the set. You should be able to just do `$filteredSet` to see the pairs of servernames and dbnames, or you can do `$filteredSet.dbname` to see just the dbnames.

Comment: That's what i mean to say the `$dbNames` doesn't have anything.